# Guava LoadingCache getAll - but without any arguments?

Tags: java, generics, caching, guava

I am using Guava LoadingCache to bulk load all elements at once into my eager cache. But the implementation of the `loadAll` method that I'm supplying does not really need an `Iterable<? extends K>` keys argument, since my DAO does not except any parameters either - my DAO method returns `generic Map<K,V>`.

Since my implementation is generic, I'm using generics to do a call on `getAllIterable(<? extends K> keys_)`, but because of the type erasure, I can not instantiate K key, and pass it to getAll, since it does not expect any non null keys.

Does anyone know of any workaround around this?

Comment: Still trying to understand what you're doing.  Do you just have a method which provides a `Map` of everything you ought to have in your cache to start with, without querying any specific keys?  Or are you trying to get _out_ all values from your cache without querying a specific key?

Comment: There is a conflict of interests here; you said you want to load all entries from the cache; what is "all"? You make it sound like this "all" is infinite

Comment: @LouisWasserman That's correct. I bulk load a map<K,V> without any specific keys

Comment: But you can't do that! You _have_ to know the keys beforehand. The fact that you can `.get()` any key on demand is what a `LoadingCache` is for

Comment: @fge - I never said I bulk load anything from the cache - I need to do a bulk load a bunch of Key/Values into LoadingCache by implementing CacheLoader<K,V> loadAll method, which is triggered whent getall method is invoked on your instance of LoadingCache class

Comment: @user3465486: This is not how you're supposed to use the `loadAll` method: you're supposed to override the `loadAll` method to load all the keys that are passed into the `loadAll` method; you shouldn't be using it to load an unrelated set of entries.  Use another mechanism to populate the cache.

Comment: @fge I understand u can not do it - since I debugged google's implementation already. I just don't want to use putAll, but to use my own implementation CacheLoader's loadAll

Comment: @user3465486: What you're saying is "I don't want to use it the way the API was designed to be used, I want to hack around it."  It's not designed to be used that way; use `putAll`.  `loadAll` is *only* designed to be used to load a group of keys passed to it in the `Iterable`, possibly in some more efficient way.

Comment: @GMoney do u got any solution for this am looking for the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the goal is just to prepopulate a `Cache` with the contents of a `Map<K, V>`, then you should just use `Cache.putAll(Map<K, V>)` to put all the entries from a specified `Map` in the cache.

Comment: I will be accepting you answer Louis - I just wanted to poke around StackOverflow if there were any alternatives to using putAll in my scenario - since I was already  providing my implementation of load method, I was hoping there was a way to utilize loadAll as well. Thanks.